# How to loop through 2 arrays and if there is a match, don't print it

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to not display numbers that are currently in the database so they can't be added twice.

My issue is that during the `foreach`, it will still show numbers I don't want shown.

Example:

In database: `foreach ($results as $item) {`

```
800-333-3333
800-222-2222
```

My list: `foreach ($obj as $file) {`

```
800-333-3333
800-222-2222
800-111-1111
```

The issue I am having is that when it loops through it will show something like this:

```
<option value="800-222-2222">" . 800-222-2222 . " - " 800-111-1111 "</option>
```

How can I ensure that the values in the database don't get shown or used at all?

**END RESULT: 
I want to have a listbox of numbers that are NOT in the database(2 foreach)**

CODE:

```
foreach ($obj as $file) {
    $c_number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $file['matchrule']);
    $clean_number = substr($c_number, 1);
    if(!empty($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $item) {
            if ($item['NUMBER'] != $clean_number) {
                echo "<option value=" . $clean_number . "|" . $_domain . ">" . $clean_number . " - " .$item['NUMBER']. "</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<option value=" . $clean_number . "|" . $_domain . ">" . $clean_number . "</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want when the values are not equal don't print them right ?

Comment: So right now your inner echo must be printing the unwanted number right and outer one printing all of them

Comment: If number matches, don't print.

Comment: Got it so remove the last echo statement and in that case whenever it doesn't match your inner echo is displaying them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understood from you:
You are retrieving data from database, And you don't want the data which is already inserted into the database be displayed.. If so, Here is the answer:
Retrieve the data from the database as an array (fetch_array) and then check if the value available in that array or not using **in_array()** function, Something like this:-

```
if(in_array($the_number, $data)) {
    echo 'The number already reserved!';
} else {
    echo 'Your number is ' . $the_number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the core concept you are trying to implement is traversal of two arrays while only outputting the elements **in** your `list` and **not in** your `database`.

Assuming your values are ordered, and exist within two separate arrays, you can use two indexes to traverse each array and only increment these indexes on certain match conditions.

An example is provided below using two arrays of integers:

```
$a = array(3, 5, 6, 11, 15, 17, 30, 31);    // Local
$b = array(2, 3, 5, 7, 15, 19, 25, 27); // Database

$i = 0;             // Index for local traverse
$j = 0;             // Index for database traverse

while ($i < count($a)) {            // Hit every local element
    if ($j >= count($b)) {      // If we're at the end of the database array, we can assume everything left in local was not in database
        echo $a[$i];                // Output an element in local, but not in database
        $i++;                     // and of course, move to the next local element
    } else if ($a[$i] == $b[$j]) {  // If the local element and the database element match
        $i++;                       // move a step through both
        $j++;
    } else if ($a[$i] > $b[$j]) {   // If local element is larger, move a step up in database
        $j++;                       // as we may still find a match later in database
    } else {                        // If local is smaller, we know that we won't find a match further in database
        echo $a[$i];                // so we can count is as existing in local, and not database
        $i++;                       // We'll also move a step forward in local, so we don't get stuck forever
    }
}
```